# Please help understand dimension of a subset of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

**True or False:** if $S$ is a subspace of dimension $3$ in $\Bbb R^4$, then there cannot exist a subspace $T$ of $\Bbb R^4$ such that $S$ is a proper subset of $T$ and $T$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb R^4$.

This is not a homework question. I'm studying for a test and this is a question from my book. I would like someone to confirm/correct my reasoning. I think the answer is true because for $S$ to be a proper subset of $T$, $T$ must have a dimension greater than $3$, i.e. $4$. But if $\dim(T) = 4$, then $T$ spans $\Bbb R^4$ and thus $T$ is not a proper subset of $\Bbb R^4$, because it equals $\Bbb R^4$.

Is this good reasoning?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help Brian.

Comment: You're welcome.